# Why I am not able to install a module "nturl2path" on my jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, module, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

This is the error that I am getting :

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install nturl2path

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement nturl2path (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for nturl2path
```

Comment: please mention the steps to reproduce so that others can see which commands you tried to install it with, just providing the error is not useful

Answer (score 1):

nturl2path is a in-built python modules that ships with Python by default. There's no need of installing it, just import it;

```py
import nturl2path
```

and start working with it.